# moving files between folders not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i'm trying to move more than one million files from one folder to another using a script but i'm not getting any results i.e no files moved and i did not get any errors,the script checks if they are more than 20 records in a folder and it moves them in another specified folder,here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "/home/admin/Lulu/Bo/"

check="ls | wc -l"
if [ $(check) -gt 1 ]
then
   find ./ -name " oAS1_201613*.tar.gz"|grep -v bak| xargs -t -I {} mv {} /RS/2011/
fi
```

any suggestion on how this can be done?

Comment: Linux don't have folders, just directories.

Comment: *script checks if they are more than **20** records* - the current code checks if they are more than **1** record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason for finding no files might be that the filename you've specified is incorrect. Do your files *really* start with a *space* character?

Is there a reason you're bothering to count the items? Wouldn't the existence of files matching your `find` criteria imply that `$(check) -gt 1`? If so, you can eliminate the check -- `find` will do nothing if it sees no files that match.

```
#!/bin/bash

src="/home/admin/Lulu/Bo/"

find "$src/" \
  -type f
  -name "oAS1_201613*.tar.gz" \
  -not -name "*bak*" \
  -print0 |
xargs -0 -t -I {} mv "{}" /RS/2011/
```

Note the `-print0` and `xargs -0`, which allow you to handle files with whitespace in their names.

Note that you could also run your `mv` as an option to `find`. Instead of `-print0`, you might use this:

```
find "$src/" ... -exec mv -v "{}" /RS/2011/ \;
```

If you REALLY wanted to emulate the functionality of `xargs -t`, you could do that via multiple `-exec` commands.

One of the benefits of using `xargs` is sometimes the `-P` option, which lets you run things in parallel. At first glance, it would seem like a "big" job of moving a million files would be a candidate for this, but it's likely you'll be IO-bound anyway, so running your mv's in parallel might not be so helpful, in which case `find .. -exec` might be just as performant as the pipe to `xargs`.

Comment: Even if you do want to check the number of files, [don't use `ls` for that](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @tripleee - yes, I think you'd be hard pressed to find any situation where I've recommended use of `ls` within a script. :) In this case, I wasn't sure whether putting a glob into an array then counting the elements would be practical.. "over a million files" is quite a few. Seemed like a better bet just to recommend not to do it at all.

Comment: btw I know you are referring to the origin post, but also instead hardcoded strings as "201613" would be better to check eg. last modified or created date- `ctime`, `mtime` parameter in `find` command :)

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx - it might indeed, if that is actually a date or time, and if that's what the OP actually wants. What would you propose that would achieve the goals stated in the question?